# Is there an event log that captures record creation / updates?

Tags: platform-event, crud, change-data-capture, event-monitoring

I am trying to find an event log that captures whether a CRUD (create, read, update, delete) event has happened on any record.

I was thinking there would be one under ApexExecution event type with a quiddity to represent record/creation, but I'm not finding a relevant attribute here or in the other event log file types.

Change Data Capture seems close, but I plan to use this event data to aggregate in datadog of how many cases, accounts, contacts created in X time frame and do not want to keep the field level data, just the high-level operation with some core meta about operation, id, and who modified it.

Alternatively, I've thought a scheduled job could work to run those queries and send the results to datadog events endpoints, but that seems hacky as opposed to consuming the events directly.

Am I missing this in the event log files / has anybody had experience in consuming record level events in a monitoring/observability tool?

Ex:

We have 10k cases being created every hour, and if cases dip to <1k being created in an hour I want to report and alert in that (from Datadog)

Comment: Would field history tracking on the object work? Then just track certain fields that you care about.

Comment: Updated my question with an example, I don't want to capture field level changes. It's really about tracking CRUD volume in realtime

Comment: why not do a scheduled job that runs every hour and counts cases created in the prior hour? and if < 10K, publish an event to Datadog - or, if the cases are created by an API, you can use the ApiEvents and filter in Datadog

Comment: @cropredy Yeah scheduled job is on the table.

 For ApiEvents platform event, I do not see anything that captures record inserts, only queries and the documentation seems to indicate the same if we look at "operation" values of Query, QueryMore, and QueryAll.

Comment: Or even a report and filter based on created date / last modified date. Then use relative dates, such as Today to get all records modified or created today. Then you save on writing code/ jobs and can make a dashboard of all these reports

Comment: I think I meant `UriEvent`, not `ApiEvent`